# page scrolled to the div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, radio-button

I have a react component, which I am using as Modal and also as element in a page. It has radio buttons.

The problem is When the user is top of the page and modal is open. If the user selects anything in modal, the page is scrolled to another element (same component) in that page which will distract the user.

Since both elements are same, selecting in one will also selects in another. Thats understandable.

I tried, onChange for radio and e.preventDefault,  but did not work.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Closest i can reproduce is https://jsfiddle.net/3tbkLxcu/

Here, preventDefault works but not in my application.

When you click on label, it will scroll to the bottom.

```
<label htmlFor="test-id" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Test radio</label>

handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to you problem, just add the following css :)

```
.ReactModal__Body--open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Hi, it did not help.

Comment: Sorry, thought you were asking about the fact that the module can still scroll after it is visible for some reason.

Comment: @Pradeepb Try writing onClick like this `onClick={ (e) => {this.handleClick(e) }`, so that you actually pass the element you clicked :)

Comment: And some reading on the use of .bind() https://medium.freecodecamp.org/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb

Comment: I have done that in my code. but still does not work.

Comment: Could you console log the variable of "e" inside the handleClick function and tell me what it returns